# Javascript issue when using Java EE Form-based Authentication

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using form based authentication to login. It works ok. I request a protected resource, I'm redirected to the login page, I login and I'm redirected to the protected page. But, the javascript from this protected page is not executed (if I reload the page it gets executed, but not the first time when I'm redirected after login). What could be the reason?

This page looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            alert('message');
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        MyPage
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: My issue seams to be related to jquery mobile. It uses ajax to load the protected page and the head script is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way. That way you guaranteed that when the body loads your function will execute. However its bad practice to include javascript in your html like this. Its better to include a js file with the code in it. Also try to use a javascripting framework like Jquery or Dojo to make your life easy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
 {
   alert("Page is loaded");
 }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
   <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```